# Combine to get new variable name

Tags: javascript

I need to get this: `$('#anchor')`

Where anc hor are variables themselves.

```
var firstPart = "anc"
var secondPart = "hor"
```

How do I do that? + to the question (sorry for that) if I have this structure:

```
<a id="233"></a><li>qwerty</li>
```

how do I addClass to this exact li that comes after #233?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer1

```
var firstPart = "anc"
var secondPart = "hor"
var selector = "#" + firstPart + secondPart;
```

Then you can call it by $(selector) .

Answer 2:

```
$(function(){
    $('#233 + li').addClass('ownclass');
});
```

Check http://jsfiddle.net/alaminopu/U2q6E/ for Answer 2.

Comment: Check the jsfiddle link. its adding class.

Answer (score 1):

First part:

```
$('#' + firstPart + secondPart); // $('#anchor')
```

Second part:

```
$('#123 + li').addClass('myclass');
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors

Answer (score 0):

`'#anchor'` is just a string. You use standard string concatination.

```
var str = '#' + firstPart + secondPart;
$(str)
```